# Number of wireless connection allowed to laptop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router

I am setting up an internet-free wireless network that consists of a laptop (Asus V551L), router (CradlePoint AER1600) and anywhere from 1-40 tablets. The laptop is running a custom application that collects data from the tablets. However, in the initial tests, I am consistently only able to get 8 devices at a time to talk with the laptop. All 40 can connect to the router, but only 8 connections reach the laptop. Is there a way to increase the number of connections or is this a max?

Comment: How much bandwidth is each connection using? Do you saturate the available bandwidth on the air channel?

Comment: This might depend on the socket level code of your custom application.

Comment: If all devices are connected to the wireless system, I'd think this is not a wireless limit but either bandwidth or application.  Have you tried pinging all the tablets from the laptop at the same time? This does not require a connection and low bandwidth

Comment: I will do a bandwidth test on each device and let you know.

Comment: I had a bandwidth monitor running on the laptop and connected individual devices to the router. Each device caused a 16KBps spike on their initial connection but it dropped to 0 once they were fully connected. I did a test data push from the laptop to 8 devices and it caused a 32KBps spike for 1 second and then returned to 0. If the tablets arent actively answering questions, there is 0 bandwidth being used.

Comment: Further testing: I deployed the application to one of my production servers running 2012 R2 and was able to connect 15 tablets right away, without issue. My assumption now is that the laptop's OS only allows 8 connections. I have another laptop I am installing Windows Server on to see if that allows the needed connection limit.

Comment: I doubt your assumption is correct. I have Windows 10 machines that makes tens of thousands of connections without issues. Torrent programs make many hundreds without issue. What precisely goes wrong when you try to make more connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear that Windows 10 has a limit of 8 connections at a time. I did several more rounds of testing and always only got 8 tablets connected at once. I had another laptop around that I was able to install Windows Server 2016 onto and (after fighting Windows Server blocking the wireless card) could promptly connect 15 tablets to.

The application will take some extra configuring for this setup, but at least I know it was the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The Desktop OSes generally have a limit of 10 simultaneous connections in Windowsland. Perhaps you could only get 8 wireless, because you were using 1 or 2 for wired access, or for other reasons that I can only speculate about. Server is the right approach to take if you want more connections simultaneously. Or you could do some kind of polling, wherein you drop some, add some, and rotate around your sender pool.
Just one of those things about Windows.

Comment: Please stop using signatures.